# singular plural depending on state

Tags: javascript, plural, singular

I'm using the script MixItUp for filtering and sorting nodes in xml files. I have a script for counting the nodes which changes upon filtering - and the count changes as it should. What the script (read: I) don't accomplish is the correct singular or plural unit after the count.

My script looks like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">$(function(){$('#miucontainer').on('mixEnd',function(e,state){$('.mixcount').html(state.totalShow+' players');});});</script>
```

I aim for a simple solution. Thank you in advance. :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to conditionally output the 's', which you're not currently doing.

```
$('.mixcount').html(state.totalShow+' player'+(state.totalShow !== 1 ? 's' : ''));
```

Comment: better to use `x != 1` 0 Points is plural ;)

Comment: @Utkanos you have a typo men  `x !== 1` ;)